# Understanding absorption law

Tags: logic, proof-explanation, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, boolean-algebra

I can't understand how absorption law is obtained. I get following steps.

$$a∨(a∧) = (a∧⊤)∨(a∧)$$
$$=(a∨a)∧(a∨b)∧(⊤∨a)∧(⊤∨b)$$
then,

I come up with $$=a∧(a∨b)∧⊤∧⊤$$ $$=a∧(a∨b)$$

But, I cannot get $\color{blue}{a∧(⊤∨)}$, as shown on [Boolean Algebra: Axiom (1 2): ∧ distributes over ∨](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Absorption_Laws_(Boolean_Algebras)), therefore $\color{blue}a$.

Can you help me? I cannot obtain $\color{blue}{a∧(⊤∨)}$. Some people say in other answers in different questions, it is obtained by distribution law. However, what I got by this is the first equation.

Comment: Note that $(a \land \top) \lor (a \land b)=a \land (\top \lor b)$ is an instance of an axiom in the system, so you can use it when you need to. You don’t need to prove it because it is already assumed in Boolean Algebra.

Comment: The second equality is unnecessary and unhelpful. From $(a \wedge \top) \vee (a \wedge b)$, by distributivity, obtain $a \wedge (\top \vee b)$ which is $a \wedge \top$ because $\top \vee x = \top$; then $a \wedge \top = a$, and that's it.

Comment: @amrsa would you mind showing that saying `by distributivity, obtain`$∧(⊤∨)$ , which I cannot achieve.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire It's the second equality of the proof in the linked page.

Comment: @amrsa, how is its 2nd step is obtained? By distribution law

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Distribution, like any other boolean algebra law, is an *equivalence* principle, and so works *both ways*.

That is, given that $$P \land (Q \lor R) = (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$$

you can not only go from $$P \land (Q \lor R)$$ to $$ (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$$

but you can also go ‘back’, i.e. go from $$(P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$$ to $$P \land (Q \lor R)$$

And yes, that doesn’t *feel * like ‘distribution’ … maybe more like ‘un-distribution’ or ‘factoring’ … but it is an application of Distribution nevertheless.

This is really not any different from basic high school algebra: we know that $3* (4 +7) = (3*4) + (3 * 7)$ … but that also means that $(3*4) + (3 *7) = 3 *(4 +7)$. Again, it can go both ways.

Comment: Thank you at first for your answer but I did already this distribution on my first equation that $∨(∧)=(∧⊤)∨(∧)$. If you can glance gracefully at the question I cannot move on to $∧(⊤∨)$.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire Going from $a \lor (a \land b)$ to $(a \land \top) \lor (a \land b)$ is *not* Distribution … not sure what your text calls it, but mine calls it Identity: $a \land \top = a$

Comment: What I mean is its continuation that $=(∨)∧(∨)∧(⊤∨)∧(⊤∨)$.  Would you mind instead showing how to obtain $∧(⊤∨)$?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire Ah! Ok, yes, that is Distribution one way, but if you can glance gracefully my answer you will see that you can also do a ‘backwards’ Distribution

Comment: before and after the text *but you can also go ‘back’, i.e. go from*, I only can see repetition, nothing else. Maybe did you write mistakenly?

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire Ok, do you recognize going from $a \land (\top \lor b)$ to $(a\land \top) \lor (a \land b)$ as an instance of Distribution?

Comment: Yes, of course.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire Ok, but since this is an *equality* you can go the other way around too, i.e. you can go from $(a \land \top) \lor (a \land b)$ to $a \land (\top \lor b)$. That is *also* Distribution.

Comment: Now, saw it. $$(∧⊤)∨(∧) = ∧(∨⊤)$$. Thank you professor. Regards.

Comment: @SonerfromTheOttomanEmpire You’re welcome! :)

Answer (score 1):

$$ a\land(\top\lor b) = (a\land \top)\lor (a\land b) $$ $$ = a \lor (a\land b) $$

Sometimes it helps starting with what you want to obtain

Answer (score 0):

You can use a truth table to prove that $P \land (Q \lor R) \iff (P \land Q) \lor (P \land R)$ is a tautology.

Using natural deduction, you can use a simple proof by cases in each direction (32 lines).

In the forward direction, consider the cases $Q$ and $R$. In the backward direction, consider the cases $P\land Q$ and $P\land R$.

Answer (score 0):

**For the sake of variety, I offer proof the two formulas are logically equivalent via primitive inference rules...**

First, proof that $p \vee (p \wedge q) \vdash p$

$\{1\} \:\:\:\:\: 1. p \vee (p \wedge q) \:\:\:\:\:$ premise

$\{2\} \:\:\:\:\: 2. p \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ Assumption

$\{3\} \:\:\:\:\: 3. p \wedge q \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ Assumption

$\{3\} \:\:\:\:\: 4. p \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ $3$ &E

$\{1\} \:\:\:\:\: 4. p \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ $1,2,2,3,4$ vE

Second, proof that $p \vdash p \vee (p \wedge q)$

$\{1\} \:\:\:\:\: 1. p \:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:\:$ premise

$\{1\} \:\:\:\:\: 2. p \vee (p \wedge q) \:\:\:\:\:$ $1$ vI

Thus, we have $p \vee (p \wedge q) \dashv \vdash p$